# Contain a text in a rectange with imgattfbbox

Tags: php, imagettftext

I have a little problem for generate a text in image with PHP. I have to get to do that:

[image: Render]

In fact, I can not make line-break. And here is my code:

```
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($bg, 0, 0, 0);
$text_font = './arial.ttf';
$text_size = 14;
$text_angle = 0;
$text_text = 'Purus aliquet rhoncus pulvinar velit, cursus diam? Montes pid augue, aliquam, porta, vel purus integer rhoncus placerat, etiam urna in, massa mus. Egestas enim, ac, hac tincidunt ac in elementum elit cursus tincidunt sed.';
$text_box = imagettfbbox($text_size, $text_angle, $text_font, $text_text);
$text_w = 280;
$text_h = 220;
$text_x = 300;
$text_y = 70;
$text_x_center = $text_x + $text_w;
$text_y_center = $text_y + $text_h;

imagettftext($bg, $text_size, $text_angle, $text_x_center, $text_y_center, $text_color, $text_font, $text_text);
```

thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea would be to use a [`stil/gd-text`](https://github.com/stil/gd-text) library in this situation.

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use GDText\Box;
use GDText\Color;

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 500);
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);

$box = new Box($im);
$box->setFontFace('./arial.ttf');
$box->setFontColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
$box->setFontSize(14);
$box->setBox(
    300, // textbox distance from left edge
    70,  // textbox distance from top edge
    280, // textbox width
    220  // textbox height
);
$box->setTextAlign('left', 'top');
$box->enableDebug(); // this line colors text for debugging purposes
$box->draw('Purus aliquet rhoncus pulvinar velit, cursus diam? Montes pid augue, aliquam, porta, vel purus integer rhoncus placerat, etiam urna in, massa mus. Egestas enim, ac, hac tincidunt ac in elementum elit cursus tincidunt sed.');
```

I think the code is self-explaining, but if you have any questions, just ask.
Demonstration:

[image: demo]